# How to make a desktop icon on centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos-7

I am new to Linux and this may sound very dumb but I need to make a desktop icon on centos 7 but I don't know how to do it. I tried googling but I can't even find Launcher. Need help

Comment: centos7 comes with gnome3. The layouts are different. It doesn't have a old gnome2 like panel and launcher. You can configure a keyboard shortcut to minimize all windows- something like `Super+D`

Comment: On the left hand side you will see a panel. Or click on the activities tab on top left corner of the screen. Go to settings -> Keyboard -> shortcuts. There you can select the shortcut key for minimizing all windows.

Comment: You may not be interested in the program eclipse, but this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtEXsNzWYlI) has been my source of knowledge. Note that you can also create desktop icons inside your Desktop folder in your home directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use of GNOME3 is assumed.

### Using a preexisting shortcut

Reference: [How to add desktop shortcut icons in RHEL7 ?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2050193) (2015) (registration required)

> 1. Click on `Home` directory on desktop. The nautilus (file browser) window will open.
> 2. Click the `Computer` tab in the left navigation panel, go to `/usr/share/applications`. All the applications icons will appear in the right browser window.
> 3. Right click desired icon (Firefox, Contacts etc)
> 4. After right clicking the icon, select `Copy To` in the context menu. A Select Destination will open up, pick Desktop folder in the left navigation panel (via left-click)
> 5. Left-click the `Select` button on the bottom right of the window.

### Using a symlink

This is an alternate technique that works as long as you know the path to the executable.

Simply create a symlink on the desktop pointing to the executable. For example:

```
$ ln -sv /full/path/to/executable ~/Desktop/
‘/home/someuser/Desktop/executable’ -> ‘/full/path/to/executable’

$ ll ~/Desktop/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 someuser someuser 57 Oct  1 19:31 executable -> /full/path/to/executable
```

The above step can actually also be done graphically using the `Files` application. To do it this way, browse to the executable, right-click, and select `Make Link`. Drag and drop the newly created link to the Desktop.

Next, graphically customize the shortcut's icon. It is not clear where this customization is stored since the shortcut is still just a symlink.

Comment: What if I need to run a program with an additional argument? e.g., /usr/local/MATLAB/bin/matlab -desktop ... Do i just have to create a small script that calls the program with the argument, and link to the script instead?

Comment: Answered my own question: Go to /usr/share/applications and create a .desktop file there. You can copy one of the existing files and just replace the relevant information the program, including the command with arguments. Then you can make a copy of that to your desktop. This is the proper way, I believe.

Answer (score 13):

Try this for creating shortcut/launcher on GNOME 3 Desktop

***Note:** I'm using CentOS 7 running GNOME 3 Desktop.*

1. Open a terminal
2. Go to Desktop directory (`/home/$yourname/Desktop/`)
3. Create a desktop file (`touch appName.desktop`)
4. Open the file and add the following content to the file (`vi appName.desktop`)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=/home/$YOURNAME/apps/scilab-6.0.0/bin/scilab
Name=scilab
Comment=
Icon=/home/$YOURNAME/apps/scilab-6.0.0/share/icons/hicolor/32x3/apps/scilab.png
Comment[en_US.utf8]=
Name[en_US]=Scilab 6.0
```

5. Change file permission to 755 (`chmod 755 appName.desktop`)

---

Variable value:

```
Terminal=<This is value is either true or false (depending on your application requirement). If it's a terminal dependency application, then true else false.>
Exec=path to your application executable
Icon=path to your app icon file (.png or .svg)
Name[en_US]=The name that will display on your desktop under the icon
```

Answer (score 3):

In this document Click means click twice

---

1. Click on Home directory on desktop. The file browser window will open.
2. Click the Computer tab in the left navigation panel, go to /usr/share/applications. All the applications icons will appear in the right browser window.
3. Right click desired icon (Firefox, Contacts, Terminal etc)
4. After right clicking the icon, select Copy To in the menu.
5. Select Copy Destination will open up, pick Home folder in the left navigation panel (via left-click)
6. Pick Desktop from the right hand panel - double click
7. Left-click the Select button on the top right of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts to panel do not work in CentOS 7.

As a work round I have been able to get something working but not ideal.
Gnome 3 seems to be a backward step from user customability point of view.

Install `gnome-shell-frippery` which modies ~/.local and 
you can configure using `Utilities -> Tweak Took` from *"Applications Menu"*.
Also you can copy `/usr/share/applications` .desktop file and copy to `~/Desktop` for shortcut
& `~/.local/share/applications` to make it appear in *"Applications Menu"* for that user only
`/usr/share/applications` for system wide in *"Applications Menu"* 
`~/.local/share/applications` for local to that user only.
You can also modify *.desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` and put in users `~/.Desktop` folder as a desktop shortcut.